# Dynamic view on SharePoint List 

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I want to create a dynamic view on my list. The list is filtered based on the current users' information coming from an external database i.e. based on which user is logged in, a value is fetched from external database and based on that value i want my SharePoint list to be filtered.

How can i do this. I am newbie in SharePoint. Any help would be really great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to implement your own custom Filter Provider web part.

The Filter Provider gets the current user ID, finds whatever info you need from your DB and then passes the filter onto the List View that displays the data.

[Writing a Filter Provider Web Part for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457205%28v=office.12%29.aspx)